# MBProgressHud Swift Compile Error when Archiving

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

I already finished my project, it works and runs perfectly on the simulator or in my own device. When I select to Archive the project to upload de build to Itunes Connect, I get all these compile errors

"Use of undeclared type MBProgressHUD"
"Use of unresolved identifier MPProgressHUD"

And so on..

NOTE: I'm using CocoaPods for this library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What solved it for me was adding `import MBProgressHUD` in the classes where I use this library, not only in the `Bridge-Header.h`

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your project build settings and find the “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section (You may find it faster to type in “Swift Compiler” into the search box to narrow down the results)

Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the name/path of your header file.  If your file resides in your project’s root folder simply put the name of the header file there.  Examples:  “ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” or simply “ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.

Refer this link http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Cocoapods Hell (a.k.a. : where the magic ends), where one must dive into his project build settings and make sense of what went wrong...

It's very hard to answer to you, as any number of reasons might be causing that.

- Do you use the same target for Build / Run & Archive ? It might be because your libPods.a isn't copied into your Archive target
- Have you installed Pods using `pod install` , have you tried playing that command again. (yes, faced with magic going wrong, one can sometimes rely on magic to save him again)
- 'Build' and 'Archive' product often differ in the build configuration they use (Build most of the time uses 'debug' configuration, while Archive uses 'release' configuration... ). Check your Pods configuration files (debug/release) and make sure they both include your `MBProgressHud`. Also, in your Project 'Info', check which pods Xcode configuration files are selected for 'debug' and 'release'

Good luck !

(PS : as `MBProgressHud` is a single file, and one you can often change, another solution is to get rid of Cocoapods and just copy/paste it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What solved it for me was adding `import MBProgressHUD` in all the classes, not only in the `Bridge-Header.h`